# Create user control fields based on bound properties

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0

I am creating a user control that I would like to be able to generate the form entry fields based on what custom data object the form is bound to. Basically, I have a drop-down box that allows the user to pick what type of data object they are working with (user, address, etc.) That choice will bind the user control to the related data object. No big deal there. I am stuck, however, on how to generate the form fields based on the properties of the object. I feel like I have seen examples of this in WPF but am not able to find them now. All form fields will be simple label, textbox combinations in a stackpanel.

I know more detial will probably be required. Let me know what specifically you would like to know. Any help of direction is greatly appreciated.

Best,

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for something which runtime generated, but check out the [Xaml Power Toys](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/xaml-power-toys/), which will do this at design time

Comment: I am actually looking for something which will generate at runtime. I would prefer not to use another tool (mainly b/c I want to be able to do it myself). However, I will check-out the XAML power toys. thanks!